# how to avoid creating entities for returning small data from database

Tags: c#-3.0

Oftentimes I need to return a list of two or three columns from a stored proc in the data layer. I usually use entities to push data back to the business/UI layer. However, I don't want to create an entity for something that is not really an entity.

Lets say I have to return a set of "date, string, string", is there any other way to do this.. for two columns, i can perhaps get away with a dictionary. I always end up creating a dummy entity but thought I'll ask this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new model to store the data:

```
public class ResultModel
{
    public DateTime DateTime1 { get; set; }
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String1 { get; set; }
}
```

then just store your data into this like so:

```
IEnumerable<ResultModel> results =
    Entities.Table.Select(r => new ResultModel
    {
        DateTime1 = r.DateTime,
        String1 = r.String1,
        String2 = r.String2
    });
```

Not verified the code but is a guide as to how to achieve this.

Comment: this can be confusing to have a random model for a data structure as an entity. In this case, I would rather create a named entity for it.

Comment: The model can be renamed of course, this is just an example. Updated name to be simpler.

Comment: I can't think of any better solution for your problem though. What else you were hoping for?

Comment: I was hoping for something like returning an anonymous type.. I did some research but didn't find anything like that.. just wanted to confirm what I was doing is ok, seems like it.

Comment: Not as far as I know. This is the best solution to that kind of common situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) for this kind of data however I've never found any real detriment to creating more understandable types, even for simple data.

Comment: I'm not using .net 4 yet. I don't think of it as a problem either but it seems unnecessary for a one time use.